# when i run this code i get ld.exe||cannot find -l-lgdi32| or |undefined reference to `__imp_SetPixel'| if i remove it

Tags: c++, codeblocks

This is test code I wrote to test out `windows.h`, but whenever I run it I get errors. First I got

```
undefined reference to `__imp_SetPixel'
```

Then I looked it up and added `-ldgi32` to the compile, but then I got:

```
ld.exe||cannot find -l-lgdi32
```

```cpp
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <bitset>
#include <ctime>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

#define M_PI   3.1415926535897932384626433832795028841971693993751058209749445923078164062862089986280348253421170679821480865132823066470938446095505822317253594081284811174502841027019385211055596446229489549303819644288109756659334461284756482337867831652712019091456485669234603486104543266482133936072602491412737245870066063155881748815209209628292540917153643678925903600113305305488204665213841469519415116094330572703657595919530921861173819326117931051185480744623799627495673518857527248912279381830119491298336733624406566430860213949463952247371907021798609437027705392171762931767523846748184676694051320005681271452635608277857713427577896091736371787214684409012249534301465495853710507922796892589235420199561121290219608640344181598136297747713099605187072113499999983729780499510597317328160963185950244594553469083026425223082533446850352619311881710100031378387528865875332083814206171776691473035982534904287554687311595628638823537875937519577818577805321712268066130019278766111959092164201989
    
#include <cmath>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;
    
int main()
{
    SetPixel(NULL, 0, 0, RGB(255, 255, 255));
}
```

Comment: Wherever you added the library try just `gdi32` since it seems there are two `-l-l` in your command line.

Comment: Note: `M_PI` is overkill. It's going to be seen by the compiler as a `double`, a type that is good to 15 digits.